# Read Specific columns from text file: R

Tags: r, performance, fread

I am trying to read text files and create a data frame (called dataset) of some specific columns (about 12) (located at certain lengths) as below:

```
  x <- fread("file1.txt",colClasses = "character", sep = "\n", header = FALSE, verbose = FALSE,strip.white = FALSE)
  y <- fread("file2.txt",colClasses = "character", sep = "\n", header = FALSE, verbose = FALSE,strip.white = FALSE)
  # combine them
  x = rbind(x,y)


  # We basically read the whole file as a string and then read substrings 
  # corresponding to each variable start and finish lengths.
  Var1= sapply(as.list(x$V1), stri_sub, from = 80, to = 82)
  Var1= as.data.frame(Var1)

  Var2= sapply(as.list(x$V1), stri_sub, 83, 89)
  Var2= as.data.frame(Var2)

  dataset = cbind(Var1,Var2)
```

It takes around 1 minute to run the two text file have 200K and 300K rows respectively. They have 1800 characters per line. Is there a faster way to run  this? I will be reading about 200 such files.

Comment: maybe try using vroom, also try to define the col types other than that consider using some parallel aproach

Comment: `stri_sub` is a vectorized function, you could probably avoid the `sapply` functions and do something like this: `stri_sub(x$V1, 83, 89)`

Comment: changing stri_sub changed 1 minute to 28 second. This is promising. I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code in the following manner

```
x <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(1:2, function(k) fread(paste0("file",k,".txt"),
                                                 colClasses = "character", 
                                                 sep = "\n", 
                                                 header = FALSE, 
                                                 verbose = FALSE,
                                                 strip.white = FALSE)))

dataset <- data.frame(Var1= substr(x$V1, 80, 82), Var2 = substr(x$V1,83,89))
```

where the second line may save more time when you use `substr` over the whole column.